# Как вывести IP и порт сервера в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Привет. Я "присоединил" к своей игре мультплеер (unity3d multiplayer tutorial помог). Всё работает идеально, но у меня только 1 вопрос: как получить IP адрес сервера и порт и вывести его в GUILayout.Label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подсказал парень с [Unity3D.ru](http://Unity3D.ru), за что ему преогромнейшие спасибо:

```
if (useNat)
 GUILayout.Label("GUID: " + Network.player.guid); //при использованиии ната IP и Port заменяет этот.. GUID номер. 
else
 GUILayout.Label("External IP/port: " + Network.player.externalIP + "/" + Network.player.externalPort);
```